# iOS Slider laggy on iPhone X simulator

Tags: ios, swift, slider, lag, iphone-x

I just drag a slider to the view in storyboard , it works fine for all other simulators except iphone X simulator....

The sliding animation become laggy in iphone X simulator. Have you guys faced the same issue ?

Comment: Are you saying that if you create an empty project and put a slider attached to no action in the view, it works fine in all other simulators *except* iPhone X?

Comment: @dfd yes , exactly

Comment: I see it too. Slow animations turned off, basic project with a slider. All I can figure, based on the answer from @Calvin is it's hardware related. I work on  2015 MacBook Pro 13" Retina, which has no dedicated graphic chip. What simulator is your Mac running on?

Comment: I should add - my work is with CoreImage. And I really don't care about how long (seconds, many seconds!) things take in the simulator because all that matters is device performance. So yeah, I never noticed this issue before. The real thing that (I think) should matter is how does things run on a *real* device? (Yes, it's a pain to deal with a strict simulator issue, but still....) Good luck!

Comment: @dfd that s my view too , but I don't have a real iphone X so that s the problem lol
btw, I work on 2016 Macbook pro with touch bar

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you do not turn on `Slow Animations` on the iPhone X simulator.

> Your Simulator > Debug > Slow Animations

Comment: Thank you for your answer Calvin , but sadly I didn't turn that on .

Comment: I don't see any problem in my iPhone X simulator, smooth. Try `Erase All Contents and Settings` and try again?